# How to handle requests from IIS to Apache?

Tags: apache, proxy, iis-6, httphandler

I need to create something like proxy between IIS and Apache
So hostheaders I would like to set up on IIS because it's Windows 2003 Server but I have some applications that should be hosted under Apache.

In this case I think that I should set up something like proxy.

Answer (score 1):

What is your primary web server? If there is none and you can distinguish different application calls (i.e. by part of URL in HTTP request), you can set up second Apache and use mod_proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). In such case you can also create your homebrew proxy which will then connect to specified server - if site load isn't too big then it's quite easy to program.

If your primary server is Apache, the mod_proxy solution will work too.

If your primary server is IIS, I don't know.

Comment: Primary web server is IIS
I have only one IP address